# remove rows from one table1 if table2 contains same value with some condition mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a query that select all rows from a `tbl_assign` where `tbl_unit_status` does not contain some values.

```
//tbl_assign

assign_id    order_id    order_no_first
---------------------------------------
    1           1              C
    2           2              C
    3           10             C
    4           11             C
    5           17             C

//tbl_unit_status

status_id    assign_id    status_status
---------------------------------------
    1            1           Cutter
    2            1           QC Jithin
    3            1           Rack
    4            1           Delivery
    5            2           Cutter
    6            3           Rack
    7            4           Cutter
    8            5           Despatch
```

the required output is,

```
assign_id    order_id    order_no_first
---------------------------------------
    2           2              C
    4           11             C
```

I want to eliminate rows from `tbl_assign` where `tbl_unit_status` contain values `Rack, Despatch, Delivery` and `QC%`

I have tried the query,

```
SELECT a.assign_id, a.order_id, a.order_no_first FROM tbl_assign a WHERE a.assign_id NOT IN (SELECT u.assign_id FROM tbl_unit_status u WHERE u.status_status NOT LIKE "QC%" OR u.status_status NOT IN ("Delivery", "Despatch", "Rack"))
```

The above code doesn't return the required output. Someone please help me.

Comment: Please tell us what output it does return.

Comment: If I get this right - you actually want to eliminate rows where 'tbl_unit_status does not contain values Rack, Despatch, Delivery and QC%'?  Your required output doesn't back this up, it list rows that do not have one of the values you've listed. (assign_id 2)

Comment: @NigelRen your assumption is wrong. I want to eliminate `assign_id` from `tbl_assign` where `tbl_unit_status` contain values `Rack, Despatch, Delivery and QC%`

Comment: Following you query, the output is: 

    assign_id  =   2, 3 and 4  and not 2 and 4. Correct?

Comment: @CarlosR : if any `assign_id` contain values `Rack, Despatch, Delivery and QC%`, that `assign_id` should be removed from `tbl_assign`

Comment: @CarlosR : for `assign_id` 3 status is `Rack`. So should be eliminated.

Comment: Yes, you eliminate assign_id 1 from tbl_assign, in this case. correct?

Comment: @CarlosR : yes.

Comment: eliminating 1,3,5

Comment: Your comment seems to contradict the actual question - in the question it says 'does not contain' in your comment it says 'contain value'.

Comment: @NigelRen : sorry. My mistake. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output:

```
assign_id | order_id | order_no_first
----------|----------|--------------
2         | 2        | C
----------|----------|--------------
4         | 11       | C
```

Code:

```
SELECT a.assign_id,
       a.order_id,
       a.order_no_first
FROM   tbl_assign a
WHERE  a.assign_id NOT IN
(
     SELECT   u.assign_id
     FROM     tbl_unit_status u
     WHERE    u.status_status IN( 'Rack', 'Despatch', 'Delivery' )
              OR u.status_status LIKE 'QC%'
);
```

Try It: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71b6b0/1/0

Summary:
Returns all rows from the `tbl_assign` table where their `assign_id` values are not correlating to those returned from sub-select.

The sub-select returns all `assign_id` values of rows from the `tbl_unit_status` table. Their `status_status` begins with 'QC' or are equal to 'Rack', 'Delivery', or 'Despatch'.

Answer (score 1):

Following you query, the output is: 
    assign_id    order_id    order_no_first

### assign_id    order_id    order_no_first

```
1           1              C
3           10             C
5           17             C
```

Try this SQL:

```html
SELECT a.assign_id, a.order_id, a.order_no_first 

FROM tbl_assign a WHERE a.assign_id NOT IN (

SELECT u.assign_id 

FROM tbl_unit_status u 

WHERE u.status_status LIKE "QC%" OR u.status_status IN ("Delivery", "Despatch", "Rack")
)
```

assign_id    order_id    order_no_first

---

```
2           2              C
4           11             C
```

Comment: eliminate 1,3,5. because it contains values `Rack or Despatch or Delivery or QC%`

Comment: Yes. only cutter will stay with id 1,2,and 4. Everything else should not appear...

Comment: `status_id = 2,3,4` contains values `Rack or Despatch or Delivery or QC%`. So `assign_id = 1` should be eliminated.

Comment: This is also true, since  Rack has assign_id = 1